# Is there a java library for the Jarque-Bera test?

Tags: java, statistics

I am currently looking for an open source java library which I can use to do the jarque-bera statistical test.

The library should include the tests' critical values for sample sizes varying between 8 and 250.

Does anybody knows such a library? All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take look at [SuanShu](http://numericalmethod.com/en/products.php). The [Javadoc](http://www.numericalmethod.com/javadoc/suanshu/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/stats/test/distribution/normality/JarqueBera.html) looks like what you want, but I'm no expert.

Comment: Thanks a lot npe! I will start looking at Suanshu right now. If this seems to do what I need, then I will let you know, so you can earn some more points by answering the question :).

Comment: Hmmz, this seems to do what I want, but it is commercial, so I do not know whether I can use this for my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for those that had the same issue as I had. I have finished this issue by creating my own implementation:

1. calculate the kurtosis and skewness yourself
2. calculate the JB test-statistic yourself.

If ever necessary, I can provide the code here.

Most of the other possible libs needed integration (R related projects) or were commercial (Suanshu).